# How can I handle prepopulated textboxes (textboxes with default descriptive text) client side?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am working with a form, and the front end devs have default text inside of the textboxes.  For instance, the zip code input box does not have a label, however, there is prepopulated text in the boxes.  here is an example of an input

```
<input id="place" name="place" type="text" value="(City, State or Zip Code)"
```

This particular input is on a search form.  This input, along with other inputs, are being passed to the server via ajax.  When the results arrive at the server, there is a post variable called "place", and if unchanged by the user, the value is "(City, State or Zip Code)".  I am wondering if there is a front end solution that I can easily implement to make it so that if the default text is not changed (nothing was entered into the input), the server will see this $_post variable as empty.  I already know that I could check on the server and see

```
if $_post[place] == "(City, State or Zip Code)"
//place is empty, omit it from the search query
```

but I am looking for a better way, if a better way exists.

How do you deal with default input text?

Thanks!

edit:  To summarise, I am looking for a way to pass this and other inputs to the server as blank if they are not changed by the user.  I would like to do it without using the aforementioned if $_post[place]...... on the serverside, and if possible, the client side as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using placeholder attribute for that: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

This will display the placeholder value, but won't send it to server.
And let older browsers gracefully degrade to empty input or fallback to JS if you want (how to check if it's supported: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

You could have the JavaScript (running in the browser) compare the current value against the default value. If it's the default value, then don't have the Ajax pass along that specific variable in the request.

Comment: that was quick!  I added a bit to the question, so you probably have not seen it.  Does there exist any way around checking is the current value == default value?  I can do the checking server-side, and I'd probably do it that way if another way does not exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Chris D.** to answer your question to **Kitsune**, if you're using jQuery, you could store the default value in `data()` on `click()` and then compare the new data vs the stored one when sending the request.
**@valentinas** `placeholder` is only supported in HTML5, so it might no be what he's looking for.

```
$('input').click(function(){ $(this).data('default', $(this).val()); });

// On your request
if ($('input').val() === $('input').data('default')) {}
```

Comment: There are ways to add fallbacks for older browsers if needed: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not a front end guy, but the placeholder sounds like it is a possible answer.  But, you are saying that this may not work in all browsers (I already know it won't work in IE, and I have not even tested it yet :p ).  I'd really like to just do the placeholder thing, but I don't want to run into bugs

Comment: If you don't polyfill then browsers that don't support `placeholder` won't show anything, not really a big deal if the `<label>` is descriptive enough.